# How to pass values from foreign key to ajax calls with django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a fairly simple model in Django:

```
class TimeReport(ValidateModelMixin, models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    TERM_CHOICES = [
        ('winter', 'winter'),
        ('summer', 'summer')
    ]
    term = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TERM_CHOICES)
...

class Person(AbstractUser):
...
```

Now, I have a view that generates a template that makes ajax calls once the page is loaded. The ajax call that requests another view:

```
def get_time_reports_api(request, year, term):
    if request.is_ajax():
        qs = TimeReport.objects.filter(year=year, term=term).all()
        return_value = serializers.serialize('json', qs)
    else:
        return_value = 'fail'

    mimetype = "application/json"
    return HttpResponse(return_value, mimetype)
```

Obviously, this view returns the foreign key within the `created_by` field.

How can I make sure I pass along the `first_name` and the `last_name` of the `Person` with each `TimeReport` entry?

If I'm not mistaken, I should use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) but I am struggling with the way it should be put together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use model manager to do that, try this:

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, first_name, last_name):
        return self.get(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)

class Person(AbstractUser):
    ...
    objects = PersonManager()

    # add this function
    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

And add `use_natural_foreign_key=True` and `use_natural_primary_keys=True` to serialize:

```
if request.is_ajax():
        qs = TimeReport.objects.filter(year=year, term=term).all()
        return_value = serializers.serialize('json', qs, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
```

Comment: I just tried what you just sent, but the code never gets called... When is `get_by_natural_key` is supposed to get called? during serialization?

Comment: @E.Jaep sorry, my mistake, that was for deserialization, I've edited my answer, try it

Comment: it indeed works. I also found the reference in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#deserialization-of-natural-keys. I also found another way to annotate through `F` function. Unfortunately, the annotations get stripped out when serialising. But that's probably for another question on Stack Overflow